# Exit code for sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have a project, build with sbt and using akka actors. I run it with "sbt 'run $args'" command and I want this program to return different exit codes depending on some condition. I use System.exit(code) from my main actor for this purposes. 
Problem, I can`t solve is that sbt exit code depends on program arguments: sometimes it exits with error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 3        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:runMain for the full output.
[error] (compile:runMain) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 3
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Dec 4, 2014 6:50:50 PM
```

that is not beauty, but that's ok.
 
But in some conditions I run System.exit(3), but sbt exits with 0 exit code and [success] message.
It there a way to force sbt to exit with the same code as my program?
P.S. I`m not sure, but looks like main difference between arguments is that in first case program is executed in one thread and in the second case it executed in more then 1 thread

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit` (or better: `sys.exit`) quits the current runtime. If sbt *forks* the runtime, then calling `sys.exit` does not quit sbt itself but just the forked process. For example, if you have `fork in Run := true`, then calling `sbt run` will make sbt spawn a second independent JVM (the purpose being that you don't want to mess around in the same JVM obviously).

In such cases, you could [define a custom run task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-create-a-custom-run-task-in-addition-to-run) that repeats the `sys.exit` for the actual sbt instance.

---

**Edit**: Here is a minimal example:

```
// project/build.properties
sbt.version = 0.13.6

// build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

lazy val myRun = taskKey[Unit]("A custom run task.")

fork in myRun := true

myRun := {
  val r   = (runner in Compile).value
  val cp  = (fullClasspath in Compile).value
  val res = r.run("foo.Bar", cp.map(_.data), Nil, streams.value.log)
  val ExitCode = "Nonzero exit code: (-?\\d+)".r
  val code = res match {
    case Some(ExitCode(c)) => c.toInt
    case _ => 0
  }
  println(s"myRun returned with $code")
  if (code != 0) sys.exit(code)
}

// src/main/scala/foo/Bar.scala 
package foo

object Bar extends App {
  println("Hello.")
  sys.exit(3)
}
```

To test: `sbt myRun`. Don't ask me why `run` returns an `Option[String]` instead of a straight `Int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get a error with this solution:  

error: symbol value ExitCode does not exist in $b001ceba8a6ab7cd4585.$sbtdef
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:

Comment: sbt uses its own Scala version independent of your project so that doesn't matter. Probably you are not using sbt 0.13. Did you see the first few lines specifying the sbt version in `project/build.properties`? I think older sbt versions use Scala 2.9 which does not have the regular expression method I'm using for `ExitCode`.